# Windows Server Backup: unable to create scheduled backup job because of disc formatting error

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-backup

I am trying to setup a scheduled backup in Windows Server Backup on a server 2012 R2 box. I can run through the process of creating the backup. I choose "backup to hard disk that is dedicated for backups". I pick an available disk (1TB disk). It gives you a notice stating it will need to reformat the selected disk which is fine. I hit finish on the confirmation and it starts a "formatting disk" process. Next I get the following error:

[image]

I have chosen internal disks and external drives (all totally new disks). Nothing seems to change. I always get the error and cannot complete the task. The disk always gets its named changed and the format is always NTFS but it will never complete and create the backup job.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This message is not complaining about your *backup* disk, it is complaining about your *source* disk.

Make sure that your source disk (i.e. the disk you are backing up) is a compatible file system (and not something like FAT or ExFAT).

Comment: Yes I was curious about that as an option but in disk management it shows selected source volumes are NTFS as well. I will work backwards on the selected sources and see if it has one as non NTFS for some reason. I guess I assumed it was an error in the destination format due to it never getting past the format disk option before throwing the error. Thanks.